# Using List.OrderBy to sort a list by positions stored in another list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have two lists, one with position variables (and other things, but that's the important part for this) and one with the elements I need to sort. Is it possible to sort my second list by the position variables in the first using OrderBy?

I could just sort it normally but I am curious about the workings of OrderBy so I would like to try that.

Thanks!

Comment: How on Earth did this get an upvote?

Comment: OrderBy cannot be used in this way, it works on objects that implement the `IComparer` interface. You'll probably need to use a foreach loop rather than LINQ to achieve this.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The [overload of OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx) lets you circumvent `IComparer`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can do the following:

```
IEnumerator<int> position = listWithPositions.GetEnumerator();
var sortedList = listToSort.OrderBy(p => 
    {
        position.MoveNext();
        return position.Current;
    }
).ToList<Object>();
```

**Edit:** I need to add that this is not good practice, you might want to consider organising your data in a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead.

Comment: @WWaldo: This solution is... let's say "bizarre". It's an attempt to re-invent zip joins badly.  **Just use a zip join**.

Comment: I don't understand your proposed sorted dictionary solution. Here, I have a list of Foos and a list of Bars, of the same length. How do I construct a sorted dictionary that has the property that the original poster wants?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to zip-join the two lists together -- zip join is a join that puts two sequences together like the two halves of a zipper, hence the name. Let's suppose you have a list of scores and a list of players such that `scores[i]` corresponds to `players[i]` for all `i`, and you wish to order the players by score:

```
List<int> scores = whatever;
List<Player> players = whatever;
List<Player> sortedPlayers = players
  .Zip(scores, (player, score) => new { player, score })
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.score)
  .Select(pair => pair.player)
  .ToList();
```

Follow along each step.

- The zip join makes a sequence of (player, score) pairs using an anonymous type. (In C# 7 you should use a tuple instead: **Exercise**: Do so.)
- We sort the list of pairs by score
- We extract the players from the sorted sequence of pairs
- We turn the sorted sequence of players into a list

and we're done.

---

Alternative solution: the above solution works for any pair of **sequences** that correspond.  If the sequences are *indexible* then we can use this alternative solution:

```
List<int> scores = whatever;
List<Player> players = whatever;
List<Player> sortedPlayers = players
  .Select((player, index) => new { player, index })
  .OrderBy(pair => scores[pair.index])
  .Select(pair => pair.player)
  .ToList();
```

Again, follow along:

- We start with a sequence of players
- We produce a sequence of (player, index) pairs, so now we know the position of each player in its list, and hence in the scores list. (Again: use a tuple in C# 7.)
- We sort the pairs by using the index to fetch the score
- We extract the players from the pairs
- We turn it into a list.